# Vertical-align for item of tag li? (i tried also "display: table-cell" but doesn't work)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I would like to have a vertical-align for text of `<li>`..
I tried also adding at tag **li**

```
display: table-cell
```

but doesn't work....

I tried adding line-heights at li with the same value of height... (works very well, but if the text of item is on two lines the effect is bad)..

```
<div id="contenitore" style="width:100%">
   <div id="dati" style="float:left"> 
    <ul style="width: 52%; padding: 0; float:left">               
            <li class="titledati">Nazione:</li>             
    </ul>
    <ul style="width: 48%; padding: 0; float:right">                
            <li class="testodati">Peru</li>                         
    </ul>    
    <ul style="clear:both"></ul>   
   </div>
   <div id="map_canvas" style="float:left">
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried adding "vertical-aling:middle" to your  div ?? make sure the parent div is set to "inline-block"

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor `vertical-aling` don't work with blocks, it's just working with text

Comment: it works with inline-block

Comment: @ yep, but you didn't noticed this

Comment: yes i tried adding "display: inline-block" to **#dati** and adding **vertical-align:middle** to <li> but nothing...

Comment: Can you add a a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) with your attempt to use `display: table-cell`? It should work when you put it in an element displayed as table.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r0r7paLd/  the problem is when for each **ul** there are more **li**, if i add **display:table-cell** the position and order changes...

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) column.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you are floating the elements. When you specify float, it sets the element's display property to block.

Comment: yes i think this the problem.... but for me is important specify float :/ is there another solution?

Comment: First of all, you need to know what you want to accomplish. you could use a table or divs with display table and the children with display:table-cell. So, if you describe/illustrate (with a drawing maybe) what you want I can help you better!

Answer (score 0):

With what you have right now `display: table-cell` can do the job. You just need to set your ul's as table and use the li's as rows. An inner div should than display as table-cell:

```
ul {
    display: table;
}
li {
    display: table-row;
}
li div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is an [update of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0r7paLd/3/.

N.B. You might want to look in a better way to layout things (without floats). Also you should remove redundant properties from your css. But that's beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: yes works but with your code doesn'works a lot of things... (margin, padding ecc ecc) :/

Comment: Well, I didn't change any of your own styles assuming you knew what to do; My bad. let me explain: Like normal table rows `display: table-row` doesn't take any formatting (no paddings etc.), this should be done on the `table-cell` element, in this case the `div`. I changed the fiddle for you so you can experiment a bit with it.

Comment: The margin didn't make sense so I also added the values of the margin to the padding and set box-sizing to content-bo.